# how to synchronize Github code with Godaddy website?

Tags: github, godaddy-api

Any idea how can synchronize my code for my website on Github to Godaddy so instead of push command to Github then upload the files manually. i just push it to Github and it automatically go to Godaddy

Answer (score 0):

You can just pull it from GitHub on your Godaddy server, e.g. with a cron job.

Comment: can you tell me the steps please